# Which all libraries for NodeJS provide persistent scheduling and cron jobs

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks

From what I have read, only **Agenda**,**Node-crontab** and **schedule-drone** provide this feature. It would be grateful if you provide a small description of the mechanism which these library use for persistent storage of jobs.

I need to send emails by reading the mail options from **MongoDB** and want my **nodeJS** application to somehow schedule and be in sych with these even if nodeJS is stopped temporarily.

Comment: Have you checked `Kue` => http://learnboost.github.io/kue/ ?

Comment: Try node-schedule. It has a very good nomenclature procedure which will help you maintain all the tasks in a orderly fashion (you can schedule each mail with a unique name which will help you cancel them easily). As far as the node killing is concerned, You'll have to create a crash recovery for that.

Comment: It would be helpful if MongoDB related libraries are suggested as I have already saved a lot of data in it and coded keep it in mind.

Comment: node-schedule or agenda

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL you can try with [nodejs-persistable-scheduler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-persistable-scheduler)

In other cases you need to build your own solution. For example, I created a collection/table to store the schedule state and rules. Then, if the service's crashes  or restarted, I can get all the schedules form the database and restart them again from the `app.listen event`.